# Ajuda com layout bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Como posso colocar abaixo do navbar do bootstrap uma barra que tenha a direita um filtro uma linha vertical e dois componentes.

Segue abaixo a imagem de como eu quero:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e como está:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o codigo html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" id="menu">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
          <li><a href="">EA TOOLS</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Capabilities</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Aplications</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Components</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Integrations</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul style="padding-right:15px;" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="#" >
              Andreia Azeredo
              <span ><img src="img/imagem.png" ></span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li><img src="img/filtro.png" ></li>
      <li><img src="img/barra.png" ></li>
      <li ><img src="img/opcao.png" ></li>
    </ol>
   </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" ">
    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Strategy Vision and Planning Enterprise ...</h3>
         <h5>It includes a ability to plan and define the company strategy to achive the </h5>
         <h5>objetives proposed to acord this mission, vision and values</h5>
         <br>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row ">
     <div class="col-sm-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default mesmo-tamanho" >Enterprise Estrategic Planning</button></div>
     <div class="col-sm-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default mesmo-tamanho">Corporate Affairs</button></div>
     <div class="col-sm-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default mesmo-tamanho">Business and Research Development</button></div>
     <div class="col-sm-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default mesmo-tamanho"><a href="grid.html">Enterprise Goivernance Risk &</a> <br><a href="grid.html">Complyance</a></button></div>
     <div class="col-sm-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default mesmo-tamanho">Sustainability & EHS Management</button></div>
    </div>
 </div>

  <div class="container-fluid">


    <div class="row ">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Mining Strategy Planning</h3>
         <h5>The ability to define a set of actions related to desire design of mine operations. it's</h5>
         <h5>prospecting activities, mining rigths managements, engineering and production planning</h5>
         <br>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row ">
     <div class="col-sm-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default mesmo-tamanho">Prospecting</button></div>
     <div class="col-sm-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default mesmo-tamanho">Sampling</button></div>
     <div class="col-sm-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default mesmo-tamanho">Rights management</button></div>
     <div class="col-sm-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default mesmo-tamanho">Mine engineering management</button></div>
     <div class="col-sm-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default mesmo-tamanho">Mine Design and Project</button></div>
     <div class="col-sm-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default mesmo-tamanho">Production Planning</button></div>
     <div class="col-sm-3"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default mesmo-tamanho"><a href="grid.html">Reconciliation</a></button></div>
    </div>
 </div>



  <script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vez de usar uma lista, nesse caso tente usa uma linha(row), algo assim:

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0">
    
    <div class="row breadcrumb">
      <div class="col-md-10 text-right">
       <img src="img/filtro.png" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 text-left">
       <img src="img/barra.png" >
       <img src="img/opcao.png" >
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sabe como eu poderia fazer para o conteudo do botão não sair dos seus limites?

Comment: Você pode definir o conteúdo com o `width:100%` ou se ficar melhor definir um `overflow:hidden` no próprio botão.

Comment: isso mesmo. obrigado pela ajuda.